# Interactive manual for clients in back-end

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-development

I don't know how to search anymore because I only get tutorials as results. 
I need a library to make a tutorial/user manual for the back-end of the application (in this case WordPress) that focuses a menu item for example and darkens the rest of the elements.
I remember seeing some library that does this but cannot remember :( where.

Some image example:
[image: example]